# Functional approach to joining an Array of values with varying separator?

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for a functional way to perform this messy procedural logic:

```
values = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
last_value = nil
string = ""
values.each do |v|
  string << if last_value && last_value.special?
    "/x/" + v.name.to_s
  else
    "/" + v.name.to_s
  end
  last_value = v
end
```

I basically have an array of objects (all the same type) and need to join their `#name` attributes, but following an object that has a particular characteristic, I need a different separator.

This is an easily solved problem, but I'm looking for the cleanest, most functional approach.  I first dived into `#inject`, but you lose the previous value at each iteration, so I couldn't make that work.  Any ideas?

I'd love to post the real code instead of pseudo code, but it's really dense and complex DataMapper Relationship stuff, so you probably couldn't just run it anyway, sorry :(

Comment: In fact, the code I post is flawed, since I'd need to drop the leading slash at the end... it's not just joined between the values.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "special" part? Do an /x/ need to be before any special, after any special or between values if one of them is special?

Comment: /x/ needs to be *after* any special, but should not finish up on the end of the output string, it should only appear in the middle (like `Array#join`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, this should work:

```
output = values.map do |v|
  ["/" + v.name.to_s, v.special? ? "/x" : ""]
end.flatten[0...-1].join
```

Alternative phrasing (Ruby 1.9):

```
output = "/" + values.flat_map do |v|
  [v.name.to_s, ("x" if v.special?)]
end.take(2*values.size - 1).join("/")
```

Without analyzing the algorithm, just making it functional:

```
output = ([nil] + values).each_cons(2).map do |last_value, v|
  if last_value && last_value.special?
    "/x/" + v.name.to_s
  else
    "/" + v.name.to_s
  end
end.join
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for introducing me to `#each_cons`, that is neat!  This may be perfect. Lemme fiddle :)

Comment: @d11wtq: note that each_cons(2) = pairwise. Look at the refactor, I think you don't need an algorithm with memory.

Comment: `each_cons` and `flat_map` seem to return Enumerators that don't work with `join` or `slice`, and calling `to_a` on them seems to just give me an Array with an Enumerator inside it, making my String a gigantic Enumerator#to_s output.  I'll keep fiddling... I think this is definitely in the direction I was thinking :)

Comment: "undefined method `join' for #<Enumerator: []:flat_map>"... this is really weird. It works with a basic Array, but doesn't seem to work with my real array of DataMapper relationships. I must be tired.

Comment: "undefined method `flatten' for #<Enumerator: []:map>" ... WTF o_O

Comment: definitely this enumerator does not behave like a enumerable, try to convert it.

Comment: Oh, wow, seems sticking `p` before a method that invokes a block actually binds the block to `p` instead of to the method you're calling.  That was so utterly confusing.  I'm still not sure how it ended up in the state it did, but it was down to my trying to print the result with `p` ;)

Answer (score 1):

try `values.collect{|v| v.special? ? v + "/x/" : v + "/"}.join("")`

EDIT, solution using inject:

`values.inject(["", ""]) {|path_and_sep, item|  [path_and_sep[0] + path_and_sep[1] + item, item.special? "/x/" : "/"]} [0]`

Comment: This is switching based on the current value.  I need to switch based on the previous value, which is where the complication lies.

Comment: insert separator after current value, not before, then. I've updated my answer.

Comment: +1 Hehe, this is true.  I did have this before, but wanted to avoid the trailing separator, since it's not easy to post-process to remove it (as it's ambiguous whether it's a value, or a separator, because they look the same).

Comment: i.e. `v` might be `x` itself, making it impossible to just chop the end of the string without knowledge of the last value.

Comment: I've changed my solution to use inject(), using an array with path created so far and next separator as an accumulator object.

Answer (score 1):

Do the join at the end to get rid of the leading and trailing `/`:

```
values.collect{|v| v.special? && v != values.last ? [v.name.to_s, "x"] : v.name.to_s}.flatten.join("/")
```

Comment: `values.last` returns the end of the Array, not the previous value in the iteration.

Comment: Ah, also, I need to switch based on the previous value, not the current one.  I'm starting to confuse even myself :P

Comment: yes, I'm comparing to the last value because I inverted the value and the separator. In your original example, the separator wouldn't be inserted **after** the last value.

Comment: Oh, wait, I think you may have solved this, sorry, misread your code!

Comment: You're absolutely right, using a sub-array like this makes things easier.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not particularly proud of that one, but it's kind of functional ;)

```
values.clone.unshift(nil).each_cons(2).map { |last_value, v|
    last_value.special? ? "/x/" + v.to_s : "/" + v.to_s
}.join()
```

The clone is needed because `each_cons` destroys he original array.

Answer (score 0):

```
values.map{|x| x.special? ? [x, SEPARATOR_2] : [x, SEPARATOR_1]}.flatten[0..-2].join('')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
values.inject('') { |m, e| m << e.to_s; m << (e.special? ? '/x/' : '/' }
```

To make it completely functional you could recreate `m` each time instead of appending to it.

And to avoid the last iteration, perhaps something more complex like:

```
delay = ''
values.inject('') do |m, e|
  m << delay << e.to_s
  delay = e.special? ? '/x/' : '/'
  m
end
```

Comment: Is the semi-colon needed?  BTW, the issue I'm having with this, is deciding how to strip off the trailing separator, since it's ambiguous if `/x/` is actually the value `x` followed by `/`, or the separator `/x/`.